# I have been makign a code with javascript that run o. while I have made it run n

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have been writing Javascript code to show a traffic light with a changing image. It uses a set array but I am new to coding and have not been told how to do this. I have written the code below but it is still not working. I can get it to run by clicking it but I need it to run without having to press the button lots of times.

It changes between images that are in the same folder as the code. I want it to work by a person only pressing the button once.

HTML:

```
<img id="light" src="traffitlr.jpeg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">changelights(and Start Lights)</button>
<button type="button" onclick=setinterval(change,1000)>start auto cycle</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var list = [
    "traffitlg.jpg",
    "traffitla.jpg",
    "traffitlr.jpg",
    "traffitly.jpg"
];


var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [
"traffitlg.jpg",
"traffitla.jpg",
"traffitlr.jpg",
"traffitly.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

var startChangeLights=function changeLights() {
    console.log("change lights");
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
    setTimeout(changeLights,6000);//change in 6 seconds ( 6000milliseconds)
    startChangeLights=function(){console.log("already started");};//prevent user from starting multiple times
}
```

Use like this:

```
startChangeLights();//change lights
startChangeLights();//already started
//after 6 s : change Lights
```

I mainly use a Timeout, that changes the lights every 6 seconds. I also use an named-anonymous function, to prevent starting twice...